# TableViewController Horizontal Scrollbar for iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview, horizontalscrollview

I have a problem with uisplitviewcontroller. master controller is a tabbarviewcontroller and child controller is just a webview.. So I show some document on the rightside and leftside i want to show document information in tableview.

As you see on the figure (i draw red rectangles), some text are not fit on the cell, and i need to scroll it, but as a default, there is no horizontal scrolling in tableview. How to solve this problem?

[image]

I am using xamarin.ios but you can provide me obj-C or swift code or algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

1 you can increase the tableView width

2 you can place UIScrollView on the cell and other labels move in that scrollView, then you can scroll the content of each cell

3 you can use UITextView in readonly mode instead of the second label in the cell, the scroll should be available automatically for the last text

Comment: thank you for your reply. the easiest seems 3. one. and I tried it, it added the vertical scroll, not horizontal.. I set it as a Editable false.. What i missed?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.. Thank you Igor for the idea..

```
public CustomInformationCell (NSString cellId,int maxLenght,int totalCharLenght)
        : base(UITableViewCellStyle.Default, cellId)
{

    _maxLength = maxLenght; //max lenght is the longest label length in order to making alignment
    SelectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None;
    Accessory = UITableViewCellAccessory.None;
    ContentView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;
    detail = new UILabel();
    caption = new UILabel ();
    caption.TextColor = UIColor.FromRGB (48,110,255);

    _scrollView = new UIScrollView {
            Frame = new CGRect (0, 0, ContentView.Bounds.Width,  ContentView.Bounds.Height),
            ContentSize = new CGSize (ContentView.Bounds.Width + totalCharLenght, ContentView.Bounds.Height),
            BackgroundColor = UIColor.White,
            AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth
        };

        _scrollView.AddSubview (caption);
        _scrollView.AddSubview (detail);

        ContentView.AddSubviews(new UIView[] {_scrollView});
        //ContentView.AddSubviews(new UIView[] {caption,  detail});
    }
```